How to properly create Python regex for allowing alphanumeric characters, commas, dots, spaces
Am working with Python, trying to allow only alphanumeric characters, commas, dots, spaces
When I run the code below, it throws error invalid syntax:
strx ='test, 22222 @% te-st test test'
result = strx.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9, .]/g, '')
print(result)


Don't use [tag:javascript] syntax? See https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html, and also read https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace

The code snippet you provided is attempting to use a syntax similar to JavaScript for regular expressions, which is not valid in Python. In Python, the replace method does not support regular expressions. Instead, you should use the re module for regex operations.
The correct way to create a regex for allowing only alphanumeric characters, commas, dots, and spaces is to use the re.sub function to substitute unwanted characters with an empty string.
import re

strx = 'test, 22222 @% te-st test test'
result = re.sub(r'[^A-Za-z0-9, .]', '', strx)
print(result)


This answer has an AI vibe. Did you write this all on your own?

This doesn't seem nearly verbose enough to be an AI-generated answer...
